# Adding rows to a table changes select index?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, ecmascript-6

I'm adding rows to a table with java script that contain a `<select>` element, every time a new row is added to the table the selected indexes change.

I've broken it down into it's simplistic form to try and recreate what is happening

```js
let currentRows = 0;
function addRow() {
 let row = 
 `<tr id="row-${currentRows}">
  <td>
    <select id="select-${currentRows}">
       <option>1</option>
       <option>2</option>
       <option>3</option>
  </select>
  </td>
 </tr>`;
 console.log(row);
 document.getElementById("myTable-body").innerHTML += row;
 currentRows = currentRows + 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick='addRow()'>Add Row</button>
 <table id="myTable">
  <tbody id='myTable-body'>
  </tbody>
 </table>
```

I would like, when a new row is added, for the selected indexes to stay at the value they are holding and not all change back to the default of 0 or -1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to play with `createElement` and `appendChild` method.

```js
let currentRows = 0;

function addRow() {
  var tr = document.createElement('tr');
  tr.setAttribute('id', 'row-' + currentRows);
  tr.innerHTML =
    `<td>
        <select id="select-${currentRows}">
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
        </select>
    </td>`;
  document.getElementById("myTable-body").appendChild(tr);
  currentRows = currentRows + 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <button onclick='addRow()'>Add Row</button>
  <table id="myTable">
    <tbody id='myTable-body'>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```